# Has that metallic sound at the end of season 8 episode 3 been used before?

Tags: game-of-thrones

At the end of *Game of Thrones* season 8 episode 3, “The Long Night”,

> Arya kills the Night King with the Catspaw dagger.

Just before that, the dagger falls in the air, in slow motion, and a metallic sound is heard.

I'm pretty sure I've heard that sound (or a very similar one) earlier in the series, but I don't remember when. Any idea?

Comment: It's a sound effect and it could be used in various places, simply there is no way to neither find nor remember a previous episode that it may be heard. Even if it is, I don't think that it answers any questions even if it has a value whatsoever.

Comment: Why the downvotes? How can I improve this question?

Comment: Downvoted are probably down to people thinking it’s just a generic noise so don’t see the point of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you mean the sound of Jon's sword before he kills the first White Walker ?

Comment: That may be it, yes. In [1:44](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qrc7N49xkYk&feature=youtu.be&t=104). I'll wait for a while in case there are other answers

Comment: Yes that was what I meant. I found it to be a quite memorable sound.

Answer (score 4):

To be honest it just sounds like a generic sound added for effect. However, in the *Game Revealed* for the episode the director of the scene talks about this being one of the few scenes that they were allowed to film in more of a fantasy esque style rather than then normal realism they go for. (Sorry no quotes, on phone will get some later.)

The only other scene I can think of off the top of my head that is filmed outside of realism is Ned Stark’s death scene back in season 1 episode 9, “Baelor”. The scene goes into a super focused and slow motion style shot and we hear the metallic sound of Ice coming down. If anything is going to match I imagine this is the best bet.